# Get record by post title in Wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, api, axios

Im trying to figure out the endpoint i need to get a record by its post title in word press. here is how i did it using id

```
var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "acf": {
    "twitter": "hello"
  }
});

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: URL/wp-json/wp/v2/team/9950', //how can i replace id with post title here
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Basic auth', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

below is how the post title json looks

```
{
    "id": 9950,
    "date": "2021-11-11T03:20:35",
    "date_gmt": "2021-11-11T03:20:35",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "URL/team/john-doe/"
    },
    "modified": "2022-08-19T14:53:46",
    "modified_gmt": "2022-08-19T14:53:46",
    "slug": "john-doe",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "team",
    "link": "URL/team/john-doe/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "John Doe" //how do i search for john doe record using title
    },
```

how can i make a get request using title instead of ID

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible by default to search by title.

Though, you can add it to rest api like this:

```
add_filter( 'rest_team_query', function( $args, $request ){
    if ( $title = $request->get_param( 'title' ) ) {
        $query = array(
                   array(
                   'key'     => 'post_title',
                   'value'   => $title,
                   'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ));
        $args['meta_query'] = $query:
    }
    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Then you can search the title like this in your api call:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/team?title=john%20doe
```